# HTML Link Behaviour (Breaks div element)

Tags: html, css, xslt, hyperlink, internet-explorer-8

Receiving odd behaviour of a link in xslt that breaks the page.

I am using XSLT to transform an XML list of manuals.  I have included a link to open the manual, (as .pdf) with a target="_blank"

In Internet Explorer 8, (Yes, we are still having to use this), the link functions normally, opening the pdf in a new window, but the page the link was one gets shifted down about 1300-1500px.  Refreshing the page fixes it, and it seems in testing that opening the same link a second time and future times it does not exibit this behaviour.

It does not shift the header or menu containers, only the body container.

I have used the developer tools to get the html it is using and do not see where or why it would be doing this.  EDIT: I see at the bottom of the html output the css and it appears to have some extreme values for positions maybe?

Relevant (HTML) code:

```
<!-- saved from url=(0071)http://www.example.com/unit/admin/instructions/instructions.xml -->
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<!-- Generated by Developer Tools. This might not be an accurate representation of the original source file -->
<HTML>
   <HEAD>
      <TITLE>Intranet</TITLE>
      <META content="text/html; charset=UTF-16" http-equiv=Content-Type>
      <SCRIPT type=text/javascript src="../../../scripts/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></SCRIPT>
      <LINK rel=stylesheet type=text/css href="../../../css/tacamo.css">
   </HEAD>
   <BODY style="ZOOM: 1">
      <DIV style="MARGIN: auto" id=wing-page-container>
         <DIV id=header-container><IMG alt="" align=middle src="../images/elements/header.png" width=1000></DIV>
            <DIV id=nav-container>
               <DIV id=menu>
                  <UL>
                     <LI><A id=menu href="http://www.example.com/unit/admin/admin.html">BACK</A></LI>
                  </UL>
               </DIV>
           </DIV>
           <DIV id=instructions-content-container>
              <TABLE class=instructions align=center>
                 <TBODY>
                    <TR>
                       <TH style="TEXT-ALIGN: center; WIDTH: 75px">Instruction Number</TH>
                       <TH style="TEXT-ALIGN: center; WIDTH: 75px">Date</TH>
                       <TH style="TEXT-ALIGN: center; WIDTH: 25px">COG</TH>
                       <TH style="WIDTH: 500px">Description</TH>
                       <TH style="TEXT-ALIGN: center; WIDTH: 50px">Open</TH>
                    </TR>
                    <TR style="BACKGROUND-COLOR: #c0d0e0">
                       <TD style="WIDTH: 75px">1</TD>
                       <TD style="TEXT-ALIGN: center; WIDTH: 75px">09/24/1997</TD>
                       <TD style="TEXT-ALIGN: center; WIDTH: 25px">GEORGE</TD>
                       <TD style="WIDTH: 500px">MANUAL ABOUT 1 THING</TD>
                       <TD style="TEXT-ALIGN: center; WIDTH: 25px"><A href="http://www.example.com/unit/admin/instructions/1-thing.pdf" target=_blank><IMG border=0 src="../images/elements/pdf-logo.gif" width=25 height=25></A></TD>
                    </TR>
                    <TR style="BACKGROUND-COLOR: #ffffff">
                       <TD style="WIDTH: 75px">2</TD>
                       <TD style="TEXT-ALIGN: center; WIDTH: 75px">03/26/2010</TD>
                       <TD style="TEXT-ALIGN: center; WIDTH: 25px">GEORGE</TD>
                       <TD style="WIDTH: 500px">MANUAL ABOUT 3 THING</TD>
                       <TD style="TEXT-ALIGN: center; WIDTH: 25px"><A href="http://www.example.com/unit/admin/instructions/2-thing.pdf" target=_blank><IMG border=0 src="../images/elements/pdf-logo.gif" width=25 height=25></A></TD>
                    </TR>
                    <TR style="BACKGROUND-COLOR: #c0d0e0">
                       <TD style="WIDTH: 75px">3</TD>
                       <TD style="TEXT-ALIGN: center; WIDTH: 75px">04/10/2014</TD>
                       <TD style="TEXT-ALIGN: center; WIDTH: 25px">GEORGE</TD>
                       <TD style="WIDTH: 500px">MANUAL ABOUT 3 THING</TD>
                       <TD style="TEXT-ALIGN: center; WIDTH: 25px"><A href="http://www.example.com/unit/admin/instructions/3-thing.pdf" target=_blank><IMG border=0 src="../images/elements/pdf-logo.gif" width=25 height=25></A></TD>
                    </TR>
                 </TBODY>
              </TABLE>
           </DIV>
           <DIV id=footer-container>
              <P class=footer>Admin POC: <A href="mailto:george@example.com">Admin ITPOC's</A> (555-1212)</P>
           </DIV>
         </DIV>
         <DIV style="BORDER-BOTTOM: #ff99cc 1px solid; TEXT-ALIGN: left; FILTER: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=80); BORDER-LEFT: #ff99cc 1px solid; PADDING-BOTTOM: 1px; LINE-HEIGHT: 100%; BACKGROUND-COLOR: #ffcccc; MARGIN: 0px; PADDING-LEFT: 1px; PADDING-RIGHT: 1px; DISPLAY: block; FONT-FAMILY: 'Sans Serif',serif; FLOAT: left; VISIBILITY: visible; COLOR: black; FONT-SIZE: 11pt; OVERFLOW: visible; BORDER-TOP: #ff99cc 1px solid; BORDER-RIGHT: #ff99cc 1px solid; PADDING-TOP: 1px; font-decoration: none" class=IEDevToolbarAddedElement>href=http://www.example.com/unit/admin/instructions/1-thing.pdf</DIV>
      </DIV>

      <DIV style="Z-INDEX: 459008; BORDER-BOTTOM: 0px; POSITION: absolute; BORDER-LEFT: 0px; PADDING-BOTTOM: 0px; LINE-HEIGHT: 0; MARGIN: 0px; PADDING-LEFT: 0px; WIDTH: 25px; PADDING-RIGHT: 0px; DISPLAY: block; HEIGHT: 25px; VISIBILITY: visible; OVERFLOW: hidden; BORDER-TOP: 0px; TOP: 5808px; BORDER-RIGHT: 0px; PADDING-TOP: 0px; LEFT: 1346px" class=IEDevToolbarAddedElement>

         <DIV style="BORDER-BOTTOM: #ff99cc 1px solid; TEXT-ALIGN: left; FILTER: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=80); BORDER-LEFT: #ff99cc 1px solid; PADDING-BOTTOM: 1px; LINE-HEIGHT: 100%; BACKGROUND-COLOR: #ffcccc; MARGIN: 0px; PADDING-LEFT: 1px; PADDING-RIGHT: 1px; DISPLAY: block; FONT-FAMILY: 'Sans Serif',serif; FLOAT: left; VISIBILITY: visible; COLOR: black; FONT-SIZE: 11pt; OVERFLOW: visible; BORDER-TOP: #ff99cc 1px solid; BORDER-RIGHT: #ff99cc 1px solid; PADDING-TOP: 1px; font-decoration: none" class=IEDevToolbarAddedElement>href=http://www.example.com/unit/admin/instructions/3-thing.pdf</DIV>
      </DIV>
   </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: I do not think XSLT is at fault. Maybe you're better off posting the HTML result and tagging the question with e.g. `internet explorer-8`.

Comment: I have to agree with Mathias Müller here, this is not an issue with your XSLT, but with how the browser renders the result HTML. Debug the fault in the HTML and then propagate a fix back into the XSLT.

Comment: Thank you both, I will do that.  Should I delete the question?  Still learning the Stack Overflow community.

Comment: @MCDewy You can **1** [self-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) your question if you've already found a solution or **2** Retag and rephrase the question as I mentioned above by editing your existing post - or **3** simply delete it, but then perhaps your problem persists?